# How does word attach templates for different users?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

If I create a word template that I put in the standard template location:

> C:\Users[ACCOUNT_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates

If I then send this to a friend to store in their templates folder (i.e. different Account_Name) then when I send them a docx file that uses the template (and has it attached), how does word know the location of their template when the file I created references my account_name?

If I just put the template in a sub folder of my document folder, then attached a docx file to it. My friend's computer would not locate the template to attach (if he does not have the 'exact' same directory).

So how does word know how to do it for different account names?

Answer (score 0):

Either you are mixing things up (do you mean styles, maybe?), or you don't know how templates work.

A template is a word document saved as a template, that once you open it as a new document, word shows you the template, but treats it as a new document.

This means that once you hit save or save as for the first time, save as is always assumed, and the template file itself is not overwritten.

Template files are dotx files rather than docx.

When you save a template file as a new docx file, it becomes a normal document, and there are no ties to the templates in any way.

When you save as a template, word automatically stores it in the template folder such that you can use new -> template, and see your template. You can even specify a network share as workplace template on every pc, and copy the templates to that folder so everyone sees those in their new list.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding templates, what you say is not fully correct. Yes a docx file will be created from a dotm file but they are not separated. If you put VBA code into a dotm file, create a dotx file from it and go into the VBA editor, you will not only see the Document1 project but also the TemplateProject and it is the TemplateProject containing all the VBA code. Therefore, the outputted docX file does have a reference (attachment) to the original template file and it is this reference for different users that is confusing me.

Comment: Just because the Docm file has the name of the template in it, does not mean its linked. Its just how VBA works. You can test this out by simply creating a new dotm file on your pc the same way you did before, now open a new document from that dotm, and save it to a docm. Now zip the dotm file into an archive and delete the dotm file itself. It no longer exists in the system, so the docm can't access it. Open the docm, and wow, it still magically sees it.

Comment: So I did as you suggested. I am actually doing a historical trace of a reporting template so the first version was a .dot file. When I removed the template, the macros also disappeared (and the associated ribbon). I then did the same trick with the .dotm file (thinking it was a historical function that had since changed) but no... that document too required the template to make the macros available (and ribbon). I returned the template in both cases and the macros (and ribbon) came back in both cases. So the template is linked to the document,

Comment: I'll have to do some testing. I don't have excel at home, only at work, but my testing when I did it back in the day told me the macro would be transferred. Maybe it is because I saved it as a dotx rather than a dotm.